# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.ScalaObject

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am running a spark code and facing below issue during running job in eclipse.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/ScalaObject
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializerManager.<init>   (SerializerManager.scala:36)
at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:266)
at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:165)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:259)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:423)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
at GroupBy.SparkDataSets.main(SparkDataSets.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.ScalaObject
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 19 more
```

I have spark version 2.0.0 and i am using scala-library version is 2.11.8 .
Please see the jar files included in eclipse.
[jars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0CR9.png)
Please find the code below that i am running in eclipse.

```
public class SparkDataSets {
private static SparkConf conf;
private static JavaSparkContext sc;
private static SQLContext sqlsc;
private static void run(String path) {
    JavaRDD<Employee> rdd = sc.textFile(path).map((t) -> {
        String[] values = t.split(",", -1);
        Employee emp = new Employee();
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-yy");
        Date startdate = dateFormat.parse(values[1]);
        Date Enddate = dateFormat.parse(values[5]);
        long start = startdate.getTime();
        long end = Enddate.getTime();
        emp.setId(Integer.parseInt(values[0]));
        emp.setStart_Date(new Timestamp(start));
        emp.setFirstName(values[2]);
        emp.setLastName(values[3]);
        emp.setGender(values[4]);
        emp.setEndDate(new Timestamp(end));
        emp.setDepartMent_id(values[6]);
        return emp;
    });
    Dataset<Employee> set = sqlsc.createDataset(rdd.rdd(),Encoders.bean(Employee.class));
    set.createOrReplaceTempView("Employee");
    Dataset<Row> filterset = sqlsc.sql("select * from Employee where lastName='Facello'");
    filterset.show();
    Dataset<Employee> bean = sqlsc.createDataset(rdd.rdd(),Encoders.bean(Employee.class));
    bean.show();
}
public static void main(String... args) {
    conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("GroupBy");
    sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    sqlsc = new SQLContext(sc);
    run("data/input/Employee.txt");
}

}
```

I have added all the required versions of Spark and scala with the exactly same in eclipse still facing the issue.Let me know the exact version of scala which i can use to resolve this.

Comment: you should upload your code and tree structure of your code. :)

Comment: Please see the code.

Comment: any solution?..